# Is there code to group similar words contained in a column

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy, jupyter-notebook

Is there code I can use to distinguish words that have similar string in Python? I want to group words, but then if I use the WHERE FUNCTION in the data frame for words like COFFEE and FEE, the words will be considered as the same, which I don't want.

The data frame looks like this:

```
id        transaction           grouping
 1         ATM FEES               FEES
 2         McDonalds              MD
 3         COFFEE SHOP            FEES
 4         POS ZARA               ZARA
 5         TASTY COFFEE           FEES
 6         FREDDIES               OTHER
 7         FEES:Monthly           FEES
 8         WITHDRAWAL FEES ATM    FEES
 9         MONTE COFFEE SHOP      FEES
```

But I want the output to look like this:

```
id        transaction            grouping
 1         ATM FEES                FEES
 2         McDonalds               MD
 3         COFFEE SHOP             COFFEE
 4         POS ZARA                ZARA
 5         TASTY COFFEE            COFFEE
 6         FREDDIES                OTHER
 7         FEES:Monthly            FEES
 8         WITHDRAWAL FEES ATM     FEES
 9         MONTE COFFEE SHOP       COFFEE
```

This is the code I used:

```
tranx['grouping'] = pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("COFFEE"),"COFFEE",
                    pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("McDonalds"), "MD",
                    pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("FEE"), "FEE",
                    pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("ZARA"), "ZARA",OTHER))))
```

Is there other code I can use to be able to distinguish COFFEE and FEE so that they are not put under the same grouping?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do, but you can check if Strings are similar with levenstein distance. Levenstein distance tells you how many "changes" have to be done, in order to get two strings that are the same. It has been well implemented in the Python Jellyfish library.

https://jellyfish.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparison.html#levenshtein-distance

Mabye this is what you are looking for. Best regards.